# Paperclip - View Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Paperclip to upload numerous files to S3 (on production) and locally (in development)

We started with images in which everything is working correctly. I recently developed a section to upload PDFs. The upload works beautifully but the view does not and this is where I need your help.

This line of code:

```
<% if product.marketing.exists? %>
```

produces this error:

```
Key name can not be empty.
```

The above code is correct according to the docs and the file information is being returned correctly from the database.

Thanks, in advance, for your help!

`-` Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some external issues at hand but FYI it's written as follows:

```
product.marketing?
```